# Configurable Map Viewer (CMV) - Content Pane with CMV

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

I’m upgrading from the old viewer to the new CMV version.

Is there a better way for handling a content pane in the sidebar under the new format? In the previous version I did it thru the controller, but this seems to be against the best practices of the new CMV. Any suggestions?

This is what I was doing: (Last portion of the posted code from Controller.js creates the content pane pictured below circled in red and adds it to the 5th position.)

[image: Content Pane with Old Viewer]

Controller.js

```
    initWidgets: function(evt) {
        var widgets = [];

        for (var key in config.widgets) {
            if (config.widgets.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var widget = lang.clone(config.widgets[key]);
                if (widget.include) {
                    widget.position = ('undefined' !== typeof(widget.position)) ? widget.position : 10000;
                    widgets.push(widget);
                }
            }
        }

        widgets.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.position - b.position;
        });

        array.forEach(widgets, function(widget, i) {
            this.widgetLoader(widget, i);
        }, this);

        var wcCP = new ContentPane({
            content: "</br><a href='#' onclick=window.open('http://oilandgas.ohiodnr.gov/')><center><img src='https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/website/oit/OilGasJS_Test/images/DOGlogo_75.png'></center></a></br><center><b>Divison of Oil & Gas</b></br>2045 Morse Rd</br>Columbus, OH 43229</br>614-265-6922</br><a href='mailto:oilandgas@dnr.state.oh.us'>oilandgas@dnr.state.oh.us</a></br><a href='#' onclick=window.open('http://oilandgas.ohiodnr.gov/')>ODNR Oil & Gas Website</a></br></br></br>Download GIS Oil & Gas Well Data:</br><a href='#' onclick=window.open('https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/website/oit/OilGasJS_Test/widgetid_help_content_data2.html')>Download Well Data by County</a></center>"
        }).placeAt(this.sidebar, 5);
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are always multiple ways to skin this configurable cat. ;) I can think at least three approaches:

1. Assuming you want your content at the bottom of the left sidebar, you can do this today in `config/viewer`:

   ```
   panes: {
       left: {},
       myContent: {
           id: 'myContent',
           placeAt: 'left',
           region: 'bottom',
           style: 'height: 220px !important;overflow:hidden',
           content: '<a href="#" onclick=window.open("http://oilandgas.ohiodnr.gov/")><center><img src="https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/website/oit/OilGasJS_Test/images/DOGlogo_75.png"></center></a></br><center><b>Divison of Oil & Gas</b></br>2045 Morse Rd</br>Columbus, OH 43229</br>614-265-6922</br><a href="mailto:oilandgas@dnr.state.oh.us">oilandgas@dnr.state.oh.us</a></br><a href="#" onclick=window.open("http://oilandgas.ohiodnr.gov/")>ODNR Oil & Gas Website</a></br></br></br>Download GIS Oil & Gas Well Data:</br><a href="#" onclick=window.open("https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/website/oit/OilGasJS_Test/widgetid_help_content_data2.html")>Download Well Data by County</a></center>'
       }
   },
   ```

This code places this new pane at the bottom of the left sidebar. Note: including the `left: {}` before your new pane is important so the left pane is created first.

If you want your content at the top of the pane, you can change the `region` accordingly. If for some reason you want your content somewhere in the middle between widgets, you cannot do that today but I like the possibilities. The next two options to accomplish this have now been logged as possible enhancement.

2. There already is a widget type of `contentPane` but today it does not use the `position` to control the placement within the parent pane. With this addition, you can create a reusable widget that you can have available for all your apps. The widget config would look something like this:

   ```
       myContent: {
           id: 'myContent',
           include: true,
           type: 'contentPane',
           position: 5,
           path: 'config/customWidgets/myContent'
       }
   ```
3. And finally, here's yet another option that I am visualizing that does not need a widget  at all:

   ```
       myContent: {
           id: 'myContent',
           include: true,
           type: 'contentPane',
           position: 5,
           content: '<a href="#" onclick=window.open("http://oilandgas.ohiodnr.gov/")><center><img src="https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/website/oit/OilGasJS_Test/images/DOGlogo_75.png"></center></a></br><center><b>Divison of Oil & Gas</b></br>2045 Morse Rd</br>Columbus, OH 43229</br>614-265-6922</br><a href="mailto:oilandgas@dnr.state.oh.us">oilandgas@dnr.state.oh.us</a></br><a href="#" onclick=window.open("http://oilandgas.ohiodnr.gov/")>ODNR Oil & Gas Website</a></br></br></br>Download GIS Oil & Gas Well Data:</br><a href="#" onclick=window.open("https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/website/oit/OilGasJS_Test/widgetid_help_content_data2.html")>Download Well Data by County</a></center>'
       }
   ```

Note the additional `content` property and the removal of `path` property since there is no widget to create.

An additional thought comes to mind that would make #1 and #3 more reusable. Instead of placing the html in content property, use an href property in the config pointing to a url on your local server. This has a slight additional advantage in that the html content will be cached by the browser.